# Jquery array dynamical initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {

    @if (myList != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in myList)
        {
            var months =new object[];
            @foreach (item1 in item)
            {
                months.push(@item1.name);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But it says that months is unaccesible. Why?

Comment: take look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556160/razor-view-engine-and-jquery

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript, at all, what so ever.

Comment: @Raynos : If I am correct that's combination of Razor View Engine and jquery...

Comment: Combining Razor and javascript is stupid. Never build JavaScript dynamically in a template.

Comment: `new object[]` does not look like valid JavaScript. Have you had a look at some [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) which explains the usage of arrays and if yes, what exactly do you have problems with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `var months =new object[];` with `var months = [];`

Comment: @teschfoobar I did, no results.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and use HTML helpers instead of mixing markup and code. E.g. the following helper

```
public static string JsArrayDeclaration(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object[] array)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.AppendFormat("var {0} = [", name);
    sb.Append(string.Join(",", array));
    sb.Append("];");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Once you import the namespace of the class containing the helper, you can easily use it in Razor with this syntax:

```
@Html.JsArrayDeclaration("months", mylist)
```

Comment: How do you mean 'import the namespace of the class containing the helper'? The helper is in the controller and the call to it is in the appropriate view.

Comment: I simply meant `@using NameSpace.Of.My.Helper;` in your view code. And the helper can't go in a controller, since it's an extension method, which must be declared in a static class.